# arcobjects modify vertices coordinate in both interior ring and exterior ring

Tags: arcobjects, vertices, ring

I have a multiple parts polygon and I want to move all vertices of this polygon. I use exteriorRingPointCollection and interiorRingPointCollection to get all vertices. But I cannot get the result I want, after run the following code, neither exterior vertices nor interior vertices changed.

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim polygon As IPolygon4 = TryCast(pFeature.Shape, IPolygon4)
Dim exteriorRingGeometryBag As IGeometryBag = polygon.ExteriorRingBag
Dim exteriorRingGeometryCollection As IGeometryCollection = TryCast(exteriorRingGeometryBag, IGeometryCollection)
Dim updCollExt As IPointCollection = New PolygonClass()
Dim updCollInt As IPointCollection = New PolygonClass()
For i = 0 To exteriorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount - 1
    Dim exteriorRingGeometry As IGeometry = xteriorRingGeometryCollection.Geometry(i)
    Dim exteriorRingPointCollection As IPointCollection = TryCast(exteriorRingGeometry, IPointCollection)

    Dim interiorRingGeometryBag As IGeometryBag = polygon.InteriorRingBag(TryCast(exteriorRingGeometry, IRing))
    Dim interiorRingGeometryCollection As IGeometryCollection = TryCast(interiorRingGeometryBag, IGeometryCollection)

    Dim InteriorRingGeometry As IGeometry = interiorRingGeometryCollection.Geometry(k)
    Dim InteriorRingPointCollection As IPointCollection = TryCast(InteriorRingGeometry, IPointCollection)
    For j = 0 To exteriorRingPointCollection.PointCount - 1
        Dim pp As IPoint = exteriorRingPointCollection.Point(j)
        Dim xvalue1 As Double = pp.X
        Dim yvalue1 As Double = pp.Y

        xValue = pp.X
        yValue = pp.Y

        pp.X = Fix(pp.X * 100) / 100
        pp.Y = Fix(pp.Y * 100) / 100
        updCollExt.AddPoint(pp)
    Next

    For k = 0 To interiorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount - 1
        For m = 0 To InteriorRingPointCollection.PointCount - 1
            Dim pp As IPoint = InteriorRingPointCollection.Point(m)
            Dim xvalue1 As Double = pp.X
            Dim yvalue1 As Double = pp.Y
            xValue = pp.X
            yValue = pp.Y

            pp.X = Fix(pp.X * 100) / 100
            pp.Y = Fix(pp.Y * 100) / 100

            updCollInt.AddPoint(pp)

        Next
    Next

    InteriorRingPointCollection = DirectCast(updCollInt, IGeometry)
Next
exteriorRingPointCollection = DirectCast(updCollExt, IGeometry)
pFeature.store()
```

Comment: Have you considered using [ITransform2D](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#itransform2d.htm) instead?

Comment: Otherwise, you can loop through all point using `IPointCollection5` and update each point using [update point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IPointCollection_UpdatePoint.htm).

Comment: The change is to approximate each coordinate to the 2nd decimal place? i.e. multiply by 100, fix, and divide by 100? Depending on the scale that might be a very small change? Or is the issue that the rest of the decimals are preserved?

Comment: Hi Kirk thanks I will try IpointCollection5

Comment: Hi AnserGIS, the issue open happens to the multiple parts polygon. Yes the change is to delete every thing from the 3rd decimal.

Comment: Hi Kirk, I am using old version of arcobjects (9.2) and IPointCollection5 is not supported :(